# Getting token error trying to run AWS Lambda locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

This is the lambda I'm trying to run/debug:

```java
package handlers;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueResult;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class StoreDataLambda implements RequestStreamHandler {

    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql:blog-post-db.cb61nkakvvkt.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            AWSSecretsManager secretsManager = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.defaultClient();
            String secretName = "prod/blogDB/dbUserPass";
            Region region = Region.of("us-east-2");

            GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest()
                    .withSecretId(secretName);

            GetSecretValueResult secretValueResult =
                    secretsManager.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);

            // Parse secret string to extract necessary values
            String secret = secretValueResult.getSecretString();
            JsonNode secretJson = mapper.readTree(secret);
            String dbUrl = DB_URL;
            String dbUsername = secretJson.get("username").asText();
            String dbPassword = secretJson.get("password").asText();

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);
            JsonNode jsonInput = mapper.readTree(input);

            // Assuming JSON structure: { "title": "value1", "content": "value2" }
            String title = jsonInput.get("title").asText();
            String content = jsonInput.get("content").asText();

            // Store data into PostgreSQL using prepared statement
            String sql = "INSERT INTO blog_page.blog_post (title, content) VALUES (?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, title);
            statement.setString(2, content);
            statement.executeUpdate();

            // Close resources
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Handle database exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the CF template I'm using:

```java
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Handler for blog post input

Resources:
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: MyLambdaFunction
      Handler: handlers.StoreDataLambda::handleRequest
      Runtime: java17
      MemorySize: 512
      CodeUri: target/BlogInputLambda-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
      Policies:
        - SecretsManagerReadWritePolicy:
            SecretName: prod/blogDB/dbUserPass
        - RDSConnectPolicy:
            DBInstanceIdentifier: blog-post-db
            Region: us-east-2
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> {"errorMessage":"The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: 95954487-215d-4181-922f-97454096389c; Proxy: null)","errorType":"com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.AWSSecretsManagerException"}

Comment: How are you supplying IAM credentials to your Lambda function? I don't see an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-role) or assignment to the Lambda function in your CF template.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to write a Lambda function that performs database operations. Next you are trying to get database values from Secret Manager. Your issue is you are trying to use AWS Credentials from an AWS Lambda function.

The solution is to use an IAM Role that has permission to perform Secret Manager operations. Then you run the Lambda function using that IAM Role. That is when you deploy the Lambda function, select that IAM Role.

Now the Lambda function will be able to retrieve values from Secrets Manager. Never try to use CREDS from a LAMBDA function. Always use an IAM Role.

Another tip -- you are using a old Java SDK which is V1. **com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManager** is V1 and **software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient** is V2.

Recommend that you upgrade to V2:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager

Comment: Switching to V2 of the secrets manager API and refactoring a little fixed this issue. It's getting the username and password for the DB. Now it's just a matter of the DB refusing the connection to localhost: 5432